# cmake error when building a c library

Tags: build, cmake

I'm trying to build the [RabbitMQ C AMQP client library](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I try to run the commands below it gives the error:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build [--config Release] .
```

> Unknown argument Release]
>
> Unknown argument .

What should the correct command be?

Comment: `--config` is an optional argument to the cmake call. The call should look like `cmake --build . --config Release`